# AttributeError: can't set attribute when trying to create database with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

trying to follow this tutorial from freecodecamp intro to flask video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RJmh_OqeA

The relevant bit of the video starts at around minute 19

This is my code:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from datetime import datetime
    
    
    app = Flask(name)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///sqlite.db'
    # initialize the database with the settings from app
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    
    class Budget_Item(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
        cost = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
        date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
        recurring = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
        due_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Budget_Item %r>' % self.id
    
    
    
    
    
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')
    
    if name == "main":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

when in the terminal I run from app import db I don't have a problem, but then when I run db.create_all() I get AttributeError: can't set attribute. I've tried changing the class name to BudgetName in case the problem was the underscore, and I've tried completely recreating the code written in the video, and I get the same error.

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mcamp/.local/share/virtualenvs/Python-docker-built-challenge-VYztjUFt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1039, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "/home/mcamp/.local/share/virtualenvs/Python-docker-built-challenge-VYztjUFt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1031, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/home/mcamp/.local/share/virtualenvs/Python-docker-built-challenge-VYztjUFt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 962, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/home/mcamp/.local/share/virtualenvs/Python-docker-built-challenge-VYztjUFt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 555, in get_engine
    options = self.get_options(sa_url, echo)
  File "/home/mcamp/.local/share/virtualenvs/Python-docker-built-challenge-VYztjUFt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 570, in get_options
    self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, sa_url, options)
  File "/home/mcamp/.local/share/virtualenvs/Python-docker-built-challenge-VYztjUFt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 914, in apply_driver_hacks
    sa_url.database = os.path.join(app.root_path, sa_url.database)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Done, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to sqlite database with flask-sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647787/cannot-connect-to-sqlite-database-with-flask-sqlalchemy)

Comment: It does indeed, thank you!!