# Flask SQLAlchemy can't set attribute error in a venv

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm learning authentication functionality with `Flask-SQLAlchemy`, so building out very basic apps where a user (attributes: name, email and password) is able to sign-up and login, get redirected to a dummy profile page, and that's it. The puzzling behaviour is the tutorials I've done won't work all the way through if I use a virtual environment.

To show this behaviour, follow [this digital ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login). At step 6, we have:

```
>>> from project import db, create_app
>>> db.create_all(app=create_app())
```

If I have the `auth` environment active (as the tutorial states I should), I get the following error message:

```
/.../flask_auth_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:833: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../flask_auth_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1039, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "/.../flask_auth_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1031, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/.../flask_auth_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 962, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/.../flask_auth_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 555, in get_engine
    options = self.get_options(sa_url, echo)
  File "/.../flask_auth_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 570, in get_options
    self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, sa_url, options)
  File "/.../flask_auth_app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 914, in apply_driver_hacks
    sa_url.database = os.path.join(app.root_path, sa_url.database)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I'll get the same error if I try to sign up a new user while running the app on `localhost` - that is, I can only successfully sign up a new user if I don't have a virtual environment running, so that the app reads from global versions of installed packages instead.

This error goes away if I deactivate the environment before running `python3`. I'll get the same behaviour if I follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYWiDiIUxQc&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&index=4), example code given [here](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog/04-Database).

#### Package Versions

This is the same in `venv` and `~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages`. I'm on a MacOS Big Sur v11.2.3.

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
SQLAlchemy==1.4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently delt with that same error message. It is actually due to an upgrade in SQLAlchemy, which gets installed as a dependency of flask-sqlalchemy.

You can find the question I posted on stackoverflow for the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647787/attributeerror-cant-set-attribute-when-connecting-to-sqlite-database-with-flas):

The problem gets solved by uninstalling SQLAlchemy==1.4.0 and installing the previous version SQLAlchemy==1.3.23.

Try doing that in your virtual environ and see if it helps.