# flask db migrate is throwing "AttributeError: can't set attribute"

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm following the flask mega tutorial, I'm currently trying to run the "flask db migrate" command but I get some errors and I'm not sure if I'm to stupid to see it but its not referring to any of my files really.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/cli.py", line 91, in migrate
    _migrate(directory, message, sql, head, splice, branch_label, version_path,
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 96, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 210, in migrate
    command.revision(config, message, autogenerate=True, sql=sql,
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 212, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 490, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 97, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 182, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "migrations/env.py", line 25, in <module>
    str(current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.engine.url).replace('%', '%%'))
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 943, in engine
    return self.get_engine()
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 962, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 555, in get_engine
    options = self.get_options(sa_url, echo)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 570, in get_options
    self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, sa_url, options)
  File "/home/moe/cryptowatch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 914, in apply_driver_hacks
    sa_url.database = os.path.join(app.root_path, sa_url.database)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score -1):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647787/attributeerror-cant-set-attribute-when-connecting-to-sqlite-database-with-flas) for more info. If you have version 1.4.0 of sqlalchemy uninstall it and install the previous version.

If your code is correct then that should solve the problem.